# How Can I solve ORA-04007

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm using toad for oracle 11g, I tried to `alter`  a `sequence` using the UI(user interface).

I want to change the `currval`.

I block with this error :

> ORA-04007: MINVALUE cannot be made to exceed the current value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not change `currval` value of pseudocolumn of a sequence directly - its value changes every time you reference `nextval` pseudocolumn of the sequence. It sounds more like you want to issue an `alter sequence` statement to change its `minvalue` parameter.

If the current value of a sequence is less than the `minval` you are trying to change to, the error will be raised. You have at least two options to get it done:

1. Recreate a sequence completely with a new value for a `minvalue` parameter
2. Change `incremet by` value, generate a next value , alter `minval` parameter and then change `increment by` value back.

Here is an example:

```
create sequence seq
increment by 1
minvalue 1

sequence SEQ created.

-- trying to change minvalue
alter sequence seq 
  minvalue 5

SQL Error: ORA-04007: MINVALUE cannot be made to exceed the current value


select seq.nextval
  from dual

NEXTVAL
------------
         1 

-- alter increment by
alter sequence seq
   increment by 4

select seq.nextval
  from dual

NEXTVAL
----------
       5 

-- altering minvalue
alter sequence seq 
  minvalue 5

sequence SEQ altered.

-- change increment by to 1 as it was before
alter sequence seq
   increment by 1

sequence SEQ altered.
```